# Oracle forms 6i validate a master detail form items one by one inside procedure/form level trigger

Tags: forms, oracle, validation, plsql

i am developing a form for a legacy application, its a simple master detail form with three fields as relation key

Master

```
DOC_TYPE,DOC_NUM,DOC_DATE,NOTES,FLAG_1
```

Detail

```
DOC_TYPE,DOC_NUM,DOC_DATE,DESC_LINE_NUM,DESC_LINE,group_ID,FLAG_2,FLAG_3
```

form background:

```
-->master block
user will enter DOC_TYPE(FROM LOV),DOC_DATE (current sysdate) ,DOC_NUM (serial)
```

then moves to

```
detail block:
here DOC_TYPE,DOC_NUM,DOC_DATE are hidden only line_num,desc line,Group_id,flag_2,flag_3 are visible.
```

now, i want to put some restrictions on it like following

when user Selects DOC_TYPE='X1'
      he should only be able to put (1,3,9,10) in group_id,
      and enter any value in only one of  flag_2 or flag_3 fields

when user select DOC_TYPE='B7'
      he should only be able to put (2,3,4,9,20) in group_id, 
      and enter any value in only one of  flag_2 or flag_3 fields

.... and a few more checks like the above

i thought about drop_down combo but the List will keep changing based on date periods

my problem i am looking for a way to validate the data entered in fields before i commit. 
validation for master block and validation for detail block all rows.

**thanks** in advance.

Comment: Cant you make it a textbox and enable type ahead? that way, evrytime when the textbox gets active, it looks for other component and fetches only the required list. Ofcourse I dont know how to do it with forms.. i Know only dojo

Comment: type ahead won't help because the value is already coming from LOV it self, i want to limit the data in lov and check all the values entered in master and detail rows to make sure they make some sense to it.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the input values in group_id, you can use record groups containing the values you want, or use LOV's. I can suggest some ways of doing it:

- 1 - Make group_id a list_item;
- 1.1 - When selecting the DOC_TYPE value, you can the repopulate the group with the values you want. Search something about POPULATE_GROUP
  and POPULATE_LIST built-in.
- 2 - Make group_id a display_item with a
  button to call a LOV that will populate it.
- 2.1 - Create two LOVs and change the property LOV_NAME on the field, or only one LOV if you can do the trick in the query.

To allow the user to enter only flag_2 or flag_3, you can change their ENABLED, or UPDATE_ALLOWED property when the value of the other one is entered. I believe you can use a WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM or POST-TEXT-ITEM to do it. Not sure if you need this restriction too, but this is my tip if you need it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it seems that it will work.